# получить в переменную по клику имя класса javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени! есть такой блок

```
<div class="seosidcon" onclick="javscript:getparm(this);"></div>
```

пробую получить функцией имя класса в переменную вот так

```
function getparm (id) {
var valuecl = id.className();
alert(valuecl);
}
```

но что то не получается, подскажите как правильней это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Опечатка во враппере `javascript:`
- `className` свойство, а не функция
- "Получить имя класса" - задача не вполне корректная, т.к. их всегда может быть несколько.
  Можно "получить значение атрибута `class`", либо "убедиться в наличии определённого класса"

```js
function getparm(el) {
  console.log(el.className);
  console.log(el.classList.contains('seosidcon'));
}
```

```html
<div class="seosidcon otherclass" onclick="javascript:getparm(this);">DIV</div>
```

Comment: а как в переменную записать можно? не подскажите? @vp_arth

Comment: `var variable = el.className` ?